# Dynamic Named range for another worksheet

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, named-ranges

I have this dynamic named range:

> = OFFSET('Sheet1'!$H$1, 0, 0, COUNTA('Sheet1'!$H$1:$H$100)-COUNTIF('Sheet1'!$H$1,0))

It only works for Sheet1.

How can I modify this formula so it works on all sheets? (There are about 20 different sheets named as "2010", "2011", etc).

Edit:

- All the sheets are structured in the same way
- This dynamic named range will be used to update charts
- Is there a way to use INDIRECT?

Comment: is this intended to extend H1 down to the last number in column H?

Comment: yes, in each sheet, the previous data in the column changes and there is one extra data point also created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need identically named Named Ranges with worksheet scope, not workbook scope.

I've modified your named range definition to the following.

```
=Sheet1!$H$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$H:$H, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet1!$H:$H))
```

This VBA will create worksheet scope named ranges for all worksheets in the loop.

```
Sub createNames()
    Dim wsn As Long, f As String

    For wsn = 2010 To 2019
        On Error GoTo next_wsn
        With Worksheets(CStr(wsn))
            On Error Resume Next
            .Names("Hnumbers").Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            f = Replace("=Sheet!R1C8:INDEX(Sheet!C8, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet!C8))", "Sheet", Format(wsn, "'0'"))
            .Names.Add Name:="Hnumbers", RefersToR1C1:=f
        End With
next_wsn:
    Next wsn
End Sub
```

Comment: In this column H, I have a formula that returns "0" if there are no values in the column beside it. Does your named range definition cover this?

Comment: No, zero is considered a number. That is why I asked earlier in the comments above. You will have to revert the formula back to that offset/counta/countif thing you were using. The important issue here is the worksheet scope names; the formula was an afterthought.

Comment: @heyitsme please mark this as an answer if it solved your problem !

Answer (score 0):

If all your sheets are structured similarly to sheet1, you can just change the "Sheet1" value within the formula to your sheet name. For example, for the 2010 worksheet, it would be:

```
= OFFSET('2010'!$H$1, 0, 0, COUNTA('2010'!$H$1:$H$100)-COUNTIF('2010'!$H$1,0))
```

Better yet, you could actually just remove the sheet name within the formula and copy it to all your sheets (don't copy the cell itself; copy the formula text and paste it on the formula bar after clicking on the cell):

```
= OFFSET($H$1, 0, 0, COUNTA($H$1:$H$100)-COUNTIF(!$H$1,0))
```

Comment: How would I link this to the charts? There are charts in each sheet